# (user error) OverlayFS - files deleted in current merged dir (mountpoint) reappear when merged dir remounted as lower

Tags: debian, overlayfs

On Debian Stretch (running as root) this the current behaviour:

```
# Create base directory
mkdir base
touch base/example

# Create merge, upper and work directories for 2 layers
mkdir layer1 layer1.upper layer1.work
mkdir layer2 layer2.upper layer2.work

# Mount layer1 as the merged directory using layer1.upper as the true upper layer,
# with base as a lower layer and layer1.work as the necessary work directory
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=$(pwd)/base,upperdir=$(pwd)/layer1.upper,workdir=$(pwd)/layer1.work layer1
ls layer1 # should show example as expected
ls layer1.upper # shows no file (this is expected behaviour, it should only show files written on layer1)
rm layer1/example
ls layer1 # should show no files
ls layer1.upper # should show a special character device called "example", this is the "whiteout" file

# unmount, and remount with layer2 being the new upper layer and using layer1.upper directory as the top level lower layer.
umount layer1
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=$(pwd)/base:$(pwd)/layer1.upper,upperdir=$(pwd)/layer2.upper,workdir=$(pwd)/layer2.work layer2
ls layer2 # now shows example again as if it was never deleted
```

Is this a bug? Or is this a limitation/expected behaviour?

If expected, any suggestions on a quick and easy workaround?

FWIW it works as desired under auFS, so one workaround is to install aufs-dkms and continue to use auFS... I may do that regardless, but I would really like clarity on whether this is a bug or expected behaviour.

---

**[update]** I was doing it wrong, please see (the now corrected) answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I've decided that this is a bug. As such, I've lodged a bug report with Debian:</s>

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896646

Oops! Turns out I was doing it wrong! As noted in response to the Debian bug:

> overlayfs is behaving as documented.  The documentation
>   (filesystems/overlayfs.txt) says: "The specified lower directories will
>   be stacked beginning from the rightmost one and going left.  In the
>   above example lower1 will be the top, lower2 the middle and lower3 the
>   bottom layer."
>
> In your example this means that "layer1.upper" is the lowest layer, and
>   its whiteout is overridden by the file in "base" which is on top of it.
>    I think you just need to swap the order of these directories in the
>   mount options.

I had read that doc, but missed the "right to left" bit!

I can confirm, that when done correctly (i.e. swapped the order so it is right to left) it works as expected.